# How does Armed // Dangerous interact with trample?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Ghor-Clan Rampager](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ghor-Clan%20Rampager) on the battlefield and I fuse [Armed/Dangerous](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Armed%2FDangerous) on it. It is going to be a 5/5 with trample and double strike, and all of my opponents creatures are going to be forced to block it.

If my opponent has [Burning-Tree Emissary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burning-Tree%20Emissary) (2/2) and [Skarrg Guildmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skarrg%20Guildmage) (2/2), which are going to block my Rampager, will the resulting damage from each combat reduce my opponent's life total? In other words: my Rampager deals 5 damage on the Emissary, which dies, and yet my opponent loses 3 life due to the trample and then another 5 due to the second strike? And then, the same thing against the Guildmage?

If that's correct, my opponent would lose 3 + 5 + 3 + 5 = 16 life, Is that correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the double strike mechanic interact with other mechanics like lifelink or trample?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5950/how-does-the-double-strike-mechanic-interact-with-other-mechanics-like-lifelink)

Comment: I think this question is sufficiently different from the linked one. The more important aspect in this question is the multiple blockers aspect rather than how trample and double strike interact.

Comment: Not a duplicate. André seems to think a 5/5 would kill two 4/4s even without Double Strike, and that's not covered by the linked question.

Comment: @Rawrgramming that is a great observation. close-vote retracted. This question could still use some editing to bring out that point.

Comment: Exactly @ikegami, that's what I was thinking. Now I got the difference. Very well explained by Rawrgramming below. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately your understanding is incorrect.

Your 5/5 Ghor-Clan Rampager with trample and double strike will be declared as an attacker, then all creatures able to block it must do so. Your opponent will declare their 2 creatures as blockers, and you will subsequently choose the order in which your ghor-clan rampager will deal its damage to those blocking creatures.

Then the first strike damage phase will occur. Your Ghor-Clan Rampager will assign it's 5 damage to the blockers in the order you chose earlier. First it must assign lethal damage to the first creature. In this case they are both 2 toughness, so 2 damage is "lethal" damage. Once lethal damage has been assigned to the first creature in the damage assignment order, you move onto the next creature with your remaining damage (3). Again assigning 2 lethal damage. At this point your creature has 1 damage left to assign, having assigned lethal damage to all its blockers. This is where trample occurs, and in the first strike step the creature deals 1 damage to your opponent.

Subsequently, these creatures die and things move on to the regular combat damage step, at this point you have 5 damage to assign, a creature without trample at this point (having killed one or more blockers in the first strike damage phase) would have nothing to assign damage to, as creatures without trample can only assign damage to the creatures that are blocking them. As your Ghor-Clan Rampager has trample, the full 5 damage from this damage phase tramples over the now dead blockers onto your opponent. This gives you a total of 6 damage trampled onto your opponent.

Answer (score 6):

When  your 5/5 doublestrike trample is blocked, you have 5 dmg to distribute amongst the defenders in the first strike part of doublestrike.

You deal 2 dmg to the Emissary, 2 to the guildmage. Thats assigning enough dmg to kill those creatures. You have 1 dmg left that is dealt to your opponent.

Then there is the normal part of the double strike. There are no defenders, so you deal 5dmg to your opponent.

In total, you dealt 10 (twice 5) damage, killing his creatures and dealing a total of 6 damage to your opponent.

Answer (score 2):

Your Rampager engages in combat with both blocking creatures at the same time, it will still only do 10 damage in total. You have to assign the first 4 damage to your opponent's creatures, and 1 trample damage can be assigned to the opponent from the first strike damage phase, then you can assign the full 5 damage from the normal damage phase to your opponent to do 6 damage in total to your opponent.

Comment: "Fight" has a specific meaning in MTG which is different from the one you used. Please avoid such confusion.